# Content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm not quite sure how to check if a message contains more than 1900 characters in length. The code below is what I currently have, however, it is still giving me the error, `DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body Content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length`.

```
if(message.length >= 1950) {
   return message.channel.send("Message must be 2000 or fewer in length.");
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `message.length` with `message.content.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `message.content.length` instead of `message.length`?

`message` is a Message Object, and `message.content` returns it's content, so to get the length of the content you must use `message.content.length`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `message.content.length`, not `message.length`. The `message` object represents a message from Discord whereas the `content` property is the string content of the message.